# **ANGULAR** styles.css:1 GET https://"www.mysite.com"/"myfont.ttf" net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

Once I updated my Angular project to **version 11** I figured this error.

the font paths are:

src/assets/fonts/myfont.eot

src/assets/fonts/myfont.svg

src/assets/fonts/myfont.ttf

src/assets/fonts/myfont.woff

**src/styles.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myfont';
  src:  url('assets/fonts/myfont.eot?tyf21e');
  src:  url('assets/fonts/myfont.eot?tyf21e#iefix')    format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('assets/fonts/myfont.ttf?tyf21e')          format('truetype'),
        url('assets/fonts/myfont.woff?tyf21e')         format('woff'),
        url('assets/fonts/myfont.svg?tyf21e#mysvg')    format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  ...
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
            ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: add a forward slash befpr assets?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ? I'm also facing similar problem so.